# How to check if a QgsGeometry is polygonal?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

In my PyQGIS code I have a `QgsGeometry`. It could be of any geometry type, maybe it is a Point, maybe a Polygon, maybe a MultiPolygon25D. How can I check if it is *any* kind of *polygonal* geometry without resorting to calculate its `.area()`?

I am not interested in the exact type of geometry, just if it is a polygonal one or not.

If possible I would like to not hardcode a list of polygonal types that QGIS currently knows but, if it exists, use some kind of abstract "`isPolygonal`" or "`isinstance(geom, PolygonalGeometry)`" if that functionality is hidden somewhere in the API.

Answer (score 1):

Use [wkbtype](https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQGis.html#a8da456870e1caec209d8ba7502cceff7):

```
types = {0: 'WKBUnknown', 1: 'WKBPoint', 
        2: 'WKBLineString', 3: 'WKBPolygon', 
        4: 'WKBMultiPoint', 5: 'WKBMultiLineString', 
        6: 'WKBMultiPolygon', 7: 'WKBNoGeometry', 
        8: 'WKBPoint25D', 9: 'WKBLineString25D', 
        10: 'WKBPolygon25D', 11: 'WKBMultiPoint25D', 
        12: 'WKBMultiLineString25D', 13: 'WKBMultiPolygon25D'}
        
g = [f.geometry() for f in iface.activeLayer().getFeatures()][0]

print(g.wkbType(), types[g.wkbType()])

6 wkbMultiPolygon
```

[image]

Comment: Is that set of types available directly from QGIS? I wouldn't want to hardcode my own dictionary there.

Comment: Sorry, I need to edit my question to clarify: I want to know if my QgsGeometry is *any* kind of polygonal and be able to proceed programmatically. I would not prefer to not hardcode a list of *current* polygonal types in QGIS if possible, who knows what types might come in the future or what I might forget-